# False colors in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I'm having troubles with videos embedded in webpages. For example, the image in attachment is a screenshot from my Facebook homepage. The static preview image is perfect, but as soon as the video starts, the colours of the video window dramatically change. My Google Chrome is updated and I haven't done any change in the last few days. Have you got any advice on how to solve this problem?

P.S.: with other browsers, e.g. Firefox, everything works perfectly.

[image: A screenshot from my Facebook home page]

Comment: What is your operating system? What graphics do you have?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit and Intel HD Graphics 4600

Comment: Open the Intel HD Graphics Control Panel (right click on desktop or go to control panel) then click "Video" make sure no one has been playing with the settings in there by clicking "Restore Defaults". Re-enable video acceleration in Chrome and test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try turning off GPU hardware video acceleration.](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/internet/how-turn-off-gpu-hardware-acceleration-in-google-chrome-3605455/) "If you're having performance issues with Google Chrome, hardware acceleration built into the web browser could be to blame."

Comment: Thanks, now it works! Can you please give me an explanation about why I've always used hw-accelleration without any problem but suddenly the problem show up? Moreover, what will be the side effect of disabling hw-video acceleration?

Comment: An educated guess: MS performed a driver update to "improve" user experience. In most cases, there is *no perceptible change* due to disabled acceleration while using the browser.  Acceleration is most helpful for games with high-speed, 3-D graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here... but I blame the Chrome (I am on dev channel, Version 58.0.3013.3 dev (64-bit)) because I am using a laptop with dedicated gpu, and tried to change the gpu to the nvidia from the intel used before... inverted colors still. Only solution is **disabling the gpu acceleration.**

Comment: The only salvageable part of this answer is redundant, it just repeats what was answered two days before. Please avoid that because this isn't a forum.

Comment: This is a 2 year old, long time solved problem, mate. You bet, I have learned to use Stackoverflow since then. Thanks for the downvote now.